# Socket-server java on apache-tomcat

Tags: java

Интересует возможность развёртывания Сокет-сервера **java** на **apache-tomcat**.

Comment: что такое сокет-сервер? вебсокет в смысле?

Comment: Сервер, построенный на классе ServerSocket

Comment: Такое возможно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059777/can-you-open-a-serversocket-from-tomcat-on-startup

Comment: Обязательно использовать сервлеты?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы такой пример:https://itnan.ru/post.php?c=1&p=267031
Работал на tomcat желательно без использования сервлетов